# Возможно ли такое с классами в Codeigniter?

Tags: yii, ооп, codeigniter

Стандартный класс **CI**:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
}
```

переписан следующим образом, расширен двумя классами:

```
class Home extends Auth {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
   }
```

Где **Auth**, класс расширяюший **MY_Controller**:

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller{
   public  $isLogged = false;
}
```

И наконец:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

В классе:

```
class Home extends Auth {
    $this->isLogged // Доступ к переменной
}
```

Свободно есть доступ к переменной **$this->isLogged**;

ВОПРОС:
Можно ли в созданной, пользовательской библиотеке получить доступ к **этой** переменной?

```
// ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКАЯ БИБЛИОТЕКА //
class CountryLang {

function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database();
   }

private function init(){
   $this->CI->isLogged; // Как здесь вывести эту переменную???
}
}
```

Comment: Несмотря на то, что эта проблема наверняка разрешается, я бы посоветовал переписать архитектуру. Потому что аутентификация есть у пользователя или в менеджере аутентификации, но не в контроллере. Контроллер, насколько понимаю, никаким сервисом (в отличие от того же пользователя) не является, и поэтому никто в самом CI наверняка не хранит на него ссылки (не говоря уж о том, что эта пользовательская библиотека начинает зависеть от кастомного контроллера).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно делаю так:

```
<?php
class home extends My_Controller{
  protected $isLogged

  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct
    $this->isLogged = $this->authLibrary->isLogged();
  }

  function index(){
    if($this->isLogged===TRUE){
    //  тут вызавается ваша бибблиотека
    }
// либо можете передать параметры в init method
    $settigs = array(
     'isLogged'=>$this->isLogged,
     'another_one'=>'...'
     );

    $this->countryLang->init($settings);

  }
}
```

Comment: Да, но это у вас класс авторизации в виде библиотеки, а у меня это контроллеер

Comment: Так какая разница. суть в этом:

      // либо можете передать параметры в init method
       $settigs = array(
        'isLogged'=>$this->isLogged,
        'another_one'=>'...'
        );

       $this->countryLang->init($settings);
Там где вы создаете этот объект.
Вы же создаете объект в контроллере?

Либо вариант 2:
При авторизации создаете сессию "isLogged"=TRUE
И потом получаете значение этой сессии в вашей библиотеке

Comment: Второй вариант с сессией понравился! Спасибо